# What is the best data structure to use to store the large student list?

Tags: data-structures

I want to write a program to store the student list(every student has name,birth day, address,.....), I want to this program is good performance for searching student(such as find student with name == 'Peter' and address='NY'), and inserting new student into list, student list is very large. I don't know what is the best data structure to use. Thank for helping.

Comment: How large is large? And how good is good?

Comment: Is the data in a database? Is it in a flat file? Is it being returned from a web service? Do you have a programming language in mind?

Comment: Use a database with appropriate indexes.

Comment: it is not a website, it is a program is written in C to demo data structure.

Comment: If you are demoing data structures, then you should implement it several different ways, and then show advantages and disadvantages. There is no best, there's optimal, and whether it is depends...

Answer (score 3):

Then you're talking about something like that:

These are advanced data structures that achieves the performance requirement you imposed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

> In computer science, a B-tree is a tree data structure that keeps data
>   sorted and allows searches, sequential access, insertions, and
>   deletions in logarithmic time. The B-tree is a generalization of a
>   binary search tree in that a node can have more than two children.
>   (Comer 1979, p. 123) Unlike self-balancing binary search trees, the
>   B-tree is optimized for systems that read and write large blocks of
>   data. It is commonly used in databases and filesystems.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

> In computing, a hash table (also hash map) is a data structure used to
>   implement an associative array, a structure that can map keys to
>   values. A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an
>   array of buckets or slots, from which the correct value can be found.

Comment: Please, choose a anwser and vote up. Its the way to thanks. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you are on the way of "reinventing the wheel". What you request is database like stuff. You can consider some in-memory database solution, such as H2 or Derby.